# Appending or creating dataframe from row slices from old dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, append, slice

I have a table in a dataframe with year columns ranging from 2001-2018 and cell values ranging from 1-9. I am attempting to loop through my original dataframe and, for each record/row, append all values for the row after the most recent occurrence of a '9'. There are some conditional requirements, but the crux of the problem that I'm having is in getting the sliced row into a new dataframe that I can export. It is currently running on 80,000 records and has only done 8,000 so it is rather inefficient. I'm also pretty confident it will not retain the whole row, but rather set the last value for each row as all cell values in the new dataframe.

Here is the output for my dataframe as a dictionary:

```
{2001L: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2002L: {0: 8.0, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2003L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: 7.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2004L: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 8.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 8.0},
 2005L: {0: 8.0, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2006L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 9.0},
 2007L: {0: nan, 1: 7.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2008L: {0: 8.0, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.5, 4: 8.0},
 2009L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2010L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2011L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2012L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2013L: {0: nan, 1: 7.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2014L: {0: nan, 1: 7.0, 2: nan, 3: 8.0, 4: 8.0},
 2015L: {0: nan, 1: 8.0, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 2016L: {0: 8.0, 1: 9.0, 2: nan, 3: 7.0, 4: 8.0},
 2017L: {0: nan, 1: 9.0, 2: nan, 3: 7.0, 4: 8.0},
 2018L: {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 7.0, 4: 9.0},
 'SegmentID': {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 17, 3: 18, 4: 19},
 'index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}}
```

Here is the output I am trying to receive as a dict.

```
{'Year0': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9},
'Year1': {0: 9.0, 1: nan, 2: 9.0},
'Year2': {0:None, 1: None, 2: None},
'index': {0: 5, 1: 7, 2: 8}}
```

Here is my code attempting to solve this problem.

```
for row in df_ratings_pivot.itertuples():
    for i in range(len(df_ratings_pivot.columns)):
        if row[i] == 9 and row[i-1] <=7 and row[i-2] <= 7:
            for j in range(0,len(df_ratings_pivot.columns)-i):
                for k in range(i,len(df_ratings_pivot.columns)):
                    df_new.set_value(row[0],'Year'+str(j),row[k])
                    print row, j, row[k]
```

Thank you!

**Edit**
Hi Ian, Here is the code I'm using to modify my dataframe. It is pretty similar to yours. The only difference that I can see is that I am reindexing the df to get segID to the end of the field list so it doesn't influence the slice

```
df_ratings_pivot
df2 = df_ratings_pivot.loc[df_ratings_pivot[df_ratings_pivot ==9].dropna(how = 'all').index]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
cols = df2.columns.tolist()
cols.insert(20, cols.pop(cols.index('SegmentID')))
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=cols)
df2
df2 = df2.astype(str)
df3 = df2.loc[:, df2.max().idxmax():]
df3
```

I just noticed the typo  for idxmax. So I fixed that and the code works, but I am only pulling the last segmentID column now and nothing else. I guess this makes sense since your code initially did not account for a segID field with such high values located at the end of the df. Is there anyway to retain SegmentID without messing up the slice?

**Edit 2**

Okay so I made your changes and here are my results in screenshot form to hopefully expedite the process. The first screenshot is me getting the DF into a format that can be modified by your code. The second part is the results of the code.

[image: Code that got me the setup DF]

[image]

Right off the bat it seems that extra information is being pulled in. For instance, record 1 should be starting at year 2016 since this is the first occurrence of a 9. That first record should only have 2 values for 2016 and 2017. Maybe I should've created a new dataframe and appended into that rather than slicing from the existing one?

My end-goal dataframe would start at some arbitrary Year0 field name which would be populated with a bunch of 9s. Everything after Year 0 would be populated with the respective record values..after the initial 9. So for records 1,2, and 3 it would go:

```
{Year0: {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9, ...},
 Year1: {0: 9, 1:nan,2:9, ...},
 Year2: {0: nan, 1: 8, 2: nan, ...},}
```

Comment: Please post your original dataframe (possibly `df.to_dict()`) and the expected output.

Comment: Should I edit the above with the entire output of df.to_dict()? And by expected output do you mean the final dataframe I wish to receive with values arranged in the desired manner? Thank you for the reply, btw

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst, "And by expected output do you mean the final dataframe I wish to receive with values arranged in the desired manner?" -- yes.

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst if `df` is too big you can just take a significative sample of it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have edited my parent message with what I think is the correct information. If I messed up somewhere I'm sorry. Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: Could you please try to reformulate your problem? I don't understand why there are 3 years only in your output.

Comment: I only created the fields for the first 3 to save time. I will update accordingly with all fields and repost. Thank you again for your continued help

Comment: I'm not understanding what the index is doing in your wanted output. Why are the values changing?

Comment: Because not all records from the original table will yield 9's. Some just have other numbers and never get a 9 and thus don't need to be appended to the new table. The different indices are from the original table. The 5th record was the first to meet the criteria for splicing and so it was the index I used when making the output df. Thinking about it now, retaining the original index isn't even important so I messed up by including it. I apologize. I just got home from work so I'll edit the parent again with a better output dictionary. Thank you both for your replies.

Comment: If your columns are supposed to be years and your rows are supposed to be the index (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) then it doesn't make sense for the 5th record in the 0th row to have a 9 since there are only 8's in that row. Please edit your question to reflect the correct output you are seeking.

Comment: You need to remove SegmentID for the `idxmax()` to work. You can join it back in later. Also, don't make every value a string, just the columns names. Please see my edits.

Comment: Thank you for baring with me up til now. I have edited the parent thread

Comment: @CambrianCatalyst, please see my newest edits. Figured out how to remove values preceding first 9.

Comment: Ian, you're the best! Your solution worked for me and got me pretty much what I needed. Thank you for sticking with me through this. I have marked your response as the solution. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get an answer up here and hopefully understand the question a bit more, here is a way to remove rows without a 9 and drop all columns before the first 9 using your sample data.

```
# make data into pd.DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# make all columns strings
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

# sort the columns
df.sort_index(axis = 1, inplace = True)

# drop index
df.drop('index', axis = 1, inplace = True)

df
```

[image: dropped index]

```
# remove 'SegmentID' for now, join later
df1 = df[df.columns.tolist()[:-1]]

# drop rows without a 9
df2 = df1.loc[df1[df1 == 9].dropna(how = 'all').index]

df2
```

[image: dropped rows]

```
# drop first columns before first occurrence of 9
df3 = df2.loc[:, df2.max().idxmax():]
```

[image: dropped unneeded columns]

```
# store index
idx = df3.index

# loop through columns to replace values != 9 with NaN preceeding first 9
for col in df3.columns:
#     remove index with 9
    idx = idx.drop(df3[df3[col] == 9].index)
#     fill values != 9 with NaN
    df3.loc[idx, col] = np.NaN
#     break out of loop when index runs out
    if len(idx) == 0:
        break

# join SegmentID back in
df3.join(df.SegmentID)
```

[image: output]

BTW, I am using Python 3.5.2, Pandas 0.20.3 in case you have syntax errors. I also converted your year columns to `str` so I could slice on the columns.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the response. Sorry for my own late response. I haven't had access to the data until today. I am having trouble getting your slice to work on my dataframe. It is important that I retain segmentID as a column so I neglected to drop that field, but I did reset the index so it was no longer used as an index. When I convert the columns to strings and apply the .loc slice I am left with the entire dataframe as it was before the slice.

Comment: Edited in parent to include typo which I initially missed.